# How to bypass call recording announcement in Android 13 , Miui 14

Tags: call, recorder

How to bypass call recording announcement in Android 13 , Miui 14 , please answer

How to bypass call recording announcement in Android 13 , Miui 14

How to bypass call recording announcement in Android 13 , Miui 14

How to bypass call recording announcement in Android 13 , Miui 14

How to bypass call recording announcement in Android 13 , Miui 14

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read tour.  Please read tour.  Please read tour.  Then maybe read tour.  Tour is fun to read.  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.